# How to print excel cell on click of drop down menu (Tkinter, Python)

Tags: python, excel, tkinter

I'm trying to print or show an individual excel cell after I click and change a drop-down menu value. I got it to print a *choice* on click. Now I want it to print/show an excel cell.

Here is what I have so far:

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

root = Tk()
root.title("The Book of Wisdom")
root.geometry("500x500")


# Load existing workbookpy-------------------------------------------------
wb = load_workbook('Test_Workbook.xlsx')
# Creat active worksheet----------------------------------------------------
ws = wb.active

prideful = ws['A2'].value
happy = ws['b3'].value

# DROP DOWN MENU vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
clicked = StringVar(root)
clicked.set("How are you feeling?")

choices = {'Prideful', 'Happy', 'Sad'}

dropDownMenu = OptionMenu(root, clicked, *choices)
dropDownMenu.pack()

def change_dropdown(*args):
    print( clicked.get() )
if choices == 'Prideful':
    print(prideful) 
   
clicked.trace('w', change_dropdown)
# DROP DOWN MENU ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


# Main Loop -------------------------------------------------------
root.mainloop()
# END ==============================================================
```

I'm trying to stick an if statement to print the 'A2' or 'prideful' excel cell. Not having any luck.

Comment: `if clicked.get() == 'Prideful': ...`

Comment: I replaced that with what I had above and it didn't print anything?